# Error connecting to db with arango shell using SSL/TLS

Tags: arangodb

I'm working with debian stretch (both client and server side).
When I try to securely connect to my arangodb server using the command-line tool arangosh by typing:

```
arangosh --server.endpoint ssl://192.168.2.11:8530
```

I get the error:

> Could not connect to endpoint 'http+ssl://192.168.2.11:8530',
>   database: '_system', username: 'root' Error message: 'Could not
>   connect to 'http+ssl://192.168.2.11:8530' 'SSL: during SSL_connect: 0
>   - Success''

The self-signed TLSv1.2 certificate I'm using seems to be working fine since the connection to the same server through the web interface does work fine. Also the insecure (non-TLS) connection both through shell and web interfaces works fine.
A simple curl test like:

```
curl -v https://192.168.2.11:8530
```

returns, among others:

> SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   *      server certificate verification OK
>   *      server certificate status verification SKIPPED

I have the root CA certificate (plain, without concatenated private key) installed under `/etc/ssl/certs`
Any idea?

Comment: When you connect to the web interface via SSL and it works, what address do you use? And what is your ssl binding in arangod.conf?

Comment: The reason I ask is because sometimes the ssl end point can be ssl://127.0.0.1:8530 and it works when you test from localhost, but won't work when from 192.168.2.11 because it doesn't match your arangod.conf binding.

Comment: I'm ashamed I forgot to check on this question of mine for a looong time: really sorry about that!

Comment: The thing is I quickly gave up on using the arangoshell for my database interaction.
Back to your comment: I tried all combinatins of using both numeric IPv4 and alphanumeric domain name both as binding options in arangod.conf and as arangoshell --server.endpoint, but to no avail.
In the end I always get:
Error message: 'Could not connect to 'http+ssl://xxx.xxx.xxx:8530' 'SSL: during SSL_connect: 0 - Success''
and a red-colored shell

Comment: Can you connect to the 8530 port using a web browser? Like firefox? Also test connecting from a web browser on the machine to the localhost address, and on another machine to the network address (e.g. 192.x.x.x)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile ArangoDB is delivered with a new OpenSSL Library, and will accept TLS 1.2.

I've [created a new dummy ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) with `-nodes`.

I've catted both into one file like this:

```
cat cert.pem key.pem > server.pem
```

I'm starting an ArangoDB daemon to use this `server.pem` like that:

```
arangod \
  --http.trusted-origin http://was-erlauben-strunz.it \ # my fake ssl CA
  --server.endpoint ssl://127.0.0.1:4529 \
  --database.directory /tmp/dummydatabase \
   --ssl.keyfile server.pem
```

And run an arangosh against it like this:

```
arangosh --server.endpoint ssl://127.0.0.1:4529
```

and it works out. If the problem persists for you please create a github issue, and share the way you created your ssl certificate.